# where do I access the comment field for a core data model to add the "xmod" for mogenerator?

Tags: core-data, mogenerator

where do I access the comment field for a core data model to add the "xmod" for mogenerator?

hopefully not too dumb a question - but I just can't see where in my existing Xcode 4 model (*.xcdatamodel) to put the "xmod" to get mogenerator working

(reference https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xmo'd currently doesn't work with Xcode4.  It is a .pbplugin and Apple removed support for them in Xcode4.  There was a couple guys working on a new way of doing it, but I haven't seen any updates in awhile on it.

You can still use the AppleScript and command line though.  You just have to manually trigger it and add the files.  You lose the automation that Xmo'd gave you.  Also, Xmo'd still works in Xcode3.  So you can switch over to it when doing your modeling if you really wanted to.

Comment: thanks - I would consider this except for warning I get with mogenerator that I don't get with the XCode4 generatored classes.  I summarised it here:  https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator/issues/55

Comment: hi Greg, you get that warning since NSObject doesn't implement the weekday method.  If you typecast it to your class you'll get rid of the warning,  [(MyManagedObject *)self.weView.weEndDayTime weekday].